# How to force curl to use more TCP connections?

Tags: c++, curl

I have a program in C++, which uses CURL to send/receive HTTP requests to read blobs in GCS (and other stuff). The ingestion throughput is ~150MBps.

By accident, I found using the [golang SDK](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage) would reach 1GBps in this same environment, accessing the same file, with the same limit for outstanding requests.

I tried to see the difference between the C++ and golang programs. One thing I noticed is the golang program establishes 45 TCP connections, while the C++/CURL program establishes only 4 connections.

I tried to set the [CURLMOPT_MAX_HOST_CONNECTIONS](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLMOPT_MAX_HOST_CONNECTIONS.html) to 0, which means unlimited, but I still get < 10 TCP connections.

I want to know, how can I make more TCP connections with CURL? It seems to me that CURL manages the connections itself?

Answer (score 0):

From the curl documentation you have an example https://curl.se/libcurl/c/10-at-a-time.html using `curl_multi_setopt`

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have already use `curl_multi_add_handle` in my code, but that doesn't seem to add conn number.